# Flash message across domains Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, subdomain

I have many subdomain dynamically added by user. I've done a redirect if the user is logged in one subdomain and try to access things in another subdomain. The only problem I'm having is the flash messages not displaying. In my `ApplicationController` I have the following method:

```
rescue_from Concerns::Subdomain::AlreadySignedIn, with: :redirect_to_current_subdomain
def redirect_to_current_subdomain
  redirect_to dashboard_url(subdomain: current_subdomain), notice: "Alredy Signedin in another subdomain"
end
```

I also have in my `initializers`

```
MyApp::Application.config.cookie_store :cookie_store, domain: :all, key: '_MyApp'
```

Comment: Before anything I have a `raise flash.inspect` in my index and it is returning a empty flash `#<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x007fb278b76010 @used=#<Set: {}>, @closed=false, @flashes={}, @now=nil>`

Comment: Flash is part of the session. Does a user's session persist across different subdomains?

Comment: It persists. The devise session is working across subdomains so the flash must persist too

Comment: Put a before filter in your application controller to log out the content of flash[:notice], and then watch your log: maybe there's another intermediate request which is meaning the flash gets wiped?